# vector de caracteres

Tags: c

El ejercicio pide para, a partir de un vector con una frase, mostrar su contenido en jerigonza (tiene que recorrer el arreglo, cuando encuentra una vocal, le agrega p+vocal. ejemplo: escondido: **e**pe **sco**po **ndi**pi **do**po).
Lo hice con switch, pero no me está funcionando. Además, lo tendría que cargar en una matriz M x N.
El código que hice es el siguiente:

```
#include<stdio.h>

char jerigonza (char frase[], int n){
    //lee frase y la guarda en el arreglo frase
    for (int i=0; i<n;i++){
        printf ("Escriba una frase:\n");
        scanf ("%s", frase);
    }

    //busca vocales y le agrega p+vocal
       for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
            switch (frase[j]){
                case 'A': case 'a': printf ("pa");
                                    break;
                case 'E': case 'e': printf ("pe");
                                    break;
                case 'I': case 'i': printf ("pi");
                                    break;
                case 'O': case 'o': printf ("po");
                                    break;
                case 'U': case 'u': printf ("pu");
                                    break;
                default: return 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
}


int main(){

char a[50];
jerigonza (a,50);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¿cuál es la salida que tenes hasta ahora?

Comment: Solo me dice. Escriba una frase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver si consigo que lo pilles:

Dado que tenemos un vector de un tamaño dado, tenemos que controlar que pintamos sólo el número de caracteres que tiene la frase que nos dan, ya que si pintamos todo el vector entero, posiblemente estemos pintando basura. Te dejo unos comentarios en el código para que te sirvan de ayuda. Saludos.

```
#include<stdio.h>

char jerigonza (char frase[], int n){
    //lee frase y la guarda en el arreglo frase
    //primero quitamos el for que lo que hacía era pedirte la frase n veces
        printf ("Escriba una frase:\n");
        scanf ("%s", frase);

    //busca vocales y le agrega p+vocal
       for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
            switch (frase[j]){
                //si hay coincidencia añadimos la 'p'
                case 'A': case 'a': printf ("pa");
                                    break;
                case 'E': case 'e': printf ("pe");
                                    break;
                case 'I': case 'i': printf ("pi");
                                    break;
                case 'O': case 'o': printf ("po");
                                    break;
                case 'U': case 'u': printf ("pu");
                                    break;
                //si hemos llegado al final de la cadena, dejamos de pintar
                case '\0': return 0;
                //si no coincide y no es fin de cadena, pintamos la letra tal cual
                default: printf("%c",frase[j]); break;
            }
        }
}


int main(){

    char a[50];
    jerigonza (a,50);

    return 0;
}
```

Salida generada:

```
Escriba una frase:
hola
hpolpa
```

Comment: Gracias @DanielGS, lo único que en el caso de "hola" tendría que salir hopolapa, ahí me está sustituyendo la vocal. Ahí tendría que agregar la vocal en el printf. Impecable!

Answer (score 0):

Disculpa el formato estoy escribiendo la respuesta desde un móvil. La explicación es la siguiente solamente tienes que agregar el printf al for así sacas la letra y si es vocal cuando entra al switch imprime el correspondiente si es vocal. Otra cosa jeringoxa ese no devuelve char cambia eso por void. Espero que esto te solucione todo. Recuerda marcar la respuesta como correcta si funciona ok. Salu2

```
//busca vocales y le agrega p+vocal 
 for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
 { 
      printf(frase[j]); 
      switch (frase[j])
      {
            case 'A': case 'a': printf ("pa"); break;
            case 'E': case 'e': printf ("pe"); break; 
            case 'I': case 'i': printf ("pi"); break; 
            case 'O': case 'o': printf ("po"); break; 
            case 'U': case 'u': printf ("pu"); break; 
            default: break; 
       } 
    }
```

Comment: Mira si no entendiste lo del void te edito la pregunta ok